# What can I find out about an embedded image in my received e-mail message?

Tags: email, gmail, privacy, tracking, privacy-protection

I believe an embedded image in a gmail message that I have received is actually a tracking link such as those used by contactmonkey.

Is there a way for me to find information about the image without providing the sender any information about myself?

Gmail's help pages claim that it prevents these trackers from providing my location information. If this is true, is there a way to cause the link to report information about my location, by activating the embedded image outside of gmail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an embedded image, then the image will be attached to the e-mail: the image link will reference this and there will be no tracking when it is displayed, because no external site is involved. Although tracking is not involved in the *display* of the image, if there is an associated link for clicking on an image, there may well be tracking information in this link.

On the other hand, as is often the case, the image may reside on an external web site, and then it often contains tracking information. The image may also have further tracking information within any link called when you click on the image.

Gmail has an option to suppress the display of images from external sites, unless you specifically request it, either for the current e-mail, or for all e-mails from the current sender. Local e-mail clients, such as Thunderbird or Outlook, have similar options, and the purpose is to prevent any tracking resulting from requesting the remote image.

If you use a local client, there is generally an option to view the unrendered source, and this allows you to investigate the source link which loads an image and the target link when you click on it. If you use Gmail's web interface, there is an option "Show original" to do the same.

If you copy the source link for an image, you can usually edit out the tracking information without affecting the image displayed, but this is not always true: sometimes the tracking determines what image will be sent. The best you can do is to try a couple of modified tracking strings and see what image appears, if any.

A couple of extra points:-

- Just because there is tracking information in a link, it doesn't necessarily mean that you are being identified personally: often its purpose is to identify the whether the e-mail has been displayed (the source link), and which image in which e-mail has induced the recipient to click (the target link), so as to assess the e-mail's effectiveness.
- If an e-mail has been sent to multiple recipients (usually in the BCC field) then the same links will be received by everyone on the list, so any tracking cannot identify individual recipients.
- Sometimes the image loaded by a tracking link is invisible, either because it is one pixel square, which is too small to notice, or because it is rendered in the background colour, so just because you don't see anything untoward when you allow remote images it doesn't mean that the display of the e-mail hasn't been tracked.

Comment: +1 for "show original" -- which revealed a link to a gif from readnotify.com. So, for the second part of my question. Presumably opening the link within gmail will not allow my location to be reported, but opening it in a browser will report whatever IP my browser is using. True?

Comment: No, not true. Gmail runs in your browser - there is no distinction between opening a link in Gmail and opening it in your browser. If you open a link, then any embedded tracking data will be sent (unless you edit it first). And your IP address is known to any remote web site you visit, unless you hide behind a proxy. Remember there are two links, the source in `<img src=...` and the target in `<a href=...`. Both may contain tracking strings, but they needn't link to the same servers.

Comment: There were included a small white gif and a non working wav. I believe the reloading of wav may be intended to estimate length of time the reloads were attempted and thereby the duration of "reading" the message. Gmail does mask location according to their documentation pages. My test readnotify account sites links opened in gmail as "opened by Google" with no geographic information. A false location may be reported by using a VPN and opening the links directly in a browser.